# Docker исходники VS Docker Бинарник

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Скажите, есть ли смысл собирать все исходники внутри контейнера или можно собрать проект на локальной машине и в докер скопировать бинарник с конфигурационными файлами?

Оба варианта у меня прекрасно работают, но прописывать сборку внутри докера довольно долго из-за того, что в проекте много сторонних библиотек, которые не так легко устанавливаются.

Собственно, если ли разница между этими подходами?

Comment: Имхо, результат работы программиста - бинарники, которые были собраны нужным компилятором и хорошенько протестированы. Сборка - это типичная ступень CI/CD процесса. А вот уже проверенные/протестированные/нужным образом пропатченные бинарники можно скидывать в контейнеры.

Comment: Насчёт «можно» стоит быть осторожным: если окружение контейнера вдруг случайно отличается от окружения локальной машины, то приложение в неродном окружении может не заработать или заработать некорректно

Comment: А вообще «много сторонних библиотек, которые не так легко устанавливаются» — это как раз отличный повод сделать контейнер, чтобы один раз наладить предсказуемый сборочный контейнер и больше никогда не мучаться с настройкой окружений локальных машин (впрочем, я не в курсе, сможет ли такое нормально интегрироваться с IDE)